# I need some help for a little SwiftUI animation

Tags: swift, animation, swiftui

I made this little animation and it works great except that the "grey background" of the main `VStack` is already at his maximum `height`.

Do you think it's possible to make the `image` appears/exists instead of working on the opacity so the "grey background" can expand when the `image` is showed?

```
import SwiftUI

struct ExampleView: View {
    @State private var isSowing = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack() {
            HStack() {
                Image("photo")
                    .onAppear { animateImage() }
                VStack() {
                    Text("Name")
                    Text("Company")
                }
                Spacer()
            }
            Image("image")
                .opacity(isSowing ? 1 : 0)
                .offset(y: isSowing ? 0 : 80)
        }
        .background(Color.grey)
    }

    private func animateImage() {
        withAnimation(.easeInOut.delay(1)) {
            isSowing = true
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the image with an `if`.

```
VStack {
    HStack() {
        ...
    }
    if isSowing {
        Image("my_image")
            .transition(.push(from: .bottom))
    }
}
.background(Color.gray)
```

I assumed you added the `.offset` modifier to achieve a "push from bottom" effect when the image appears. You can instead do this with a `transition` instead.

<sup>(IMHO `.push(from: .top)` looks better)</sup>

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about `push`. Actually, the effect of `bottom` is really beautiful. But only available on iOS 16 or higher!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want "image" to appear at the same time as the background, perhaps dropping down from behind the initial content? This is possible with the following changes:

- make the image an overlay over the background
- add bottom padding to allow space for the image
- reveal the image + background by using a masking layer that is animated.

This approach reserves all the space needed when the view first appears, so the size of the `VStack` doesn't change when the animation happens. Any content that follows the `VStack` will not move when the image is revealed.

Here you go, hope it's what you wanted:

```swift
struct ExampleView: View {
    @State private var isShowing = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack() {
            HStack() {
                Image(systemName: "person.fill") // "photo"
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .padding()
                    .frame(width: 70, height: 70)
                    .onAppear { animateImage() }
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text("Name")
                    Text("Company")
                }
                Spacer()
            }
            .padding(.bottom, 80)
        }
        .background {
            Color.gray
                .overlay(alignment: .bottom) {
                    Image(systemName: "fossil.shell.fill") // "image"
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFit()
                        .padding()
                        .frame(width: 80, height: 80)
                }
                .overlay(alignment: .bottom) {
                    Color(UIColor.systemBackground)
                        .frame(height: isShowing ? 0 : 80)
                }
        }
    }

    private func animateImage() {
        withAnimation(.easeInOut.delay(1)) {
            isShowing = true
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Fossil]

Comment: Thanks for this. The benefit is it's working with iOS 15 but it's more lines of code.